# VM queue configuration with mule requester

Tags: queue, mule, virtual-machine

I am trying to read data from VM queue using Mule requester.

What should I give in the Queue Path for VM queue?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of examples available for this type of configuration available across various forums and [Github](https://gist.github.com/adrianhsieh/bf88c3cb60a9d34c3461). One such example is available in the [MuleSoft Support Knowledge Base](https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/Persistent-VM-queue-muleContext-is-null). I have additionally provided an Example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns:mulerequester="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mulerequester" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mulerequester http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/mulerequester/current/mule-mulerequester.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd">
    <flow name="mule-requester-demo-vmFlow">
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <set-payload value="#[message.id]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </poll>
        <vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" path="my.data.queue" doc:name="VM"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="mule-requester-demo-vmFlow1">
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="5000"/>
            <logger message="&quot;Getting Messages&quot;" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </poll>
        <mulerequester:request-collection resource="vm://my.data.queue" doc:name="Mule Requester"/>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each">
            <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </foreach>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

You can play with the poll frequencies, and the settings on the Mule Requester to return a collection (Request-Collection) or one message in order to get the idea of the module.